# Enabling Wi-Fi disables 3G service  (ZTE Warp running Shinjitsu 1.5b)

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, wi-fi, custom-roms, 3g

I just started using this ZTE Warp (on Boost Mobile) yesterday. I rooted and ROM'd it with Clockwork Mod and Shinjitsu 1.5b (1.5.1c and 1.5.1c-beta2 did not work, for some reason).

Everything is pretty awesome so far, but whenever I enable Wi-Fi, I lose all 3G service - not just data, I can't send or receive calls or texts - the phone says 'No Service'.

Any ideas? I'm pretty new to Android.

Answer (score 2):

Just disable wifi. I have 1.5.1c Beta 2. Look for ccrusher1 on the forum, and message me if you need more help.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I don't mind running without Wi-Fi, but it's nice to have, as I'm replacing my iPod Touch and cellphone with the Warp... so I use it as a mini-tablet and media player, too.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I went over to the Android forums and asked... apparently, it's a known bug in all overclocked versions of Shinjitsu. I installed the non-overclocked kernel (as an update.zip from the SD card, with Clockwork) and it's been almost two hours and everything is working perfectly!